# What is the set of cardinals of the remainders of compactifications of $\mathbb R$?

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, forcing

If $c:\mathbb R\to c\mathbb R$ is a compactification of $\mathbb R$ then the cardinality $K=|c\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb R|$ of the remainder can be  $\mathfrak c=2^{\aleph_0}$ or (at most) $|\beta \mathbb R\setminus \mathbb R|= 2^{\mathfrak c},$ and if $K<\mathfrak c$ then $K=1$ or $K=2$.

What other values of $K$ are consistently possible?

Let $S=\{t\in \mathrm{Card}: \mathfrak c\le t\le 2^{\mathfrak c}\}.$ Let $T$ be the set of uncountable cardinals of remainders of compactifications of $\mathbb R.$ Is it consistent that $T\ne S$? If so, is there any constraint on members of $S \setminus T$? Are there some forcing constructions that can address this?

Comment: Do you have a reference for $K < \mathfrak{c} \to K \le 2$? I only know it for finite remainders.

Comment: This can be rephrased into a question on the cardinality of the spectra of quotients of sub C*-algebras of $C_b(\Bbb R)$. I know that independence results concerning the pure state space of C*-algebras have been studied by various people, but I don't know if there's anything relevant to this question known from that angle

Comment: I imagine that $S$ might also omit things of countable cofinality. No idea why, just a hunch.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma. The space $U=c\Bbb R$ \ $\Bbb R$ is compact & has at most 2 isolated points.  So if $K>2$ and we remove the isolated points of $U$ from $U$ then we get a non-empty compact Hausdorff space with no isolated points, which must have cardinal $\ge c.$

Comment: @AsafKaragila . I had that  hunch too, but no ideas.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma . Let $p$ be an isolated point of $c\Bbb R$ \ $\Bbb R.$ Let  $V$ be open in $c\Bbb R$ with $V=\{p\} \cup (V\cap \Bbb R)$ and $Cl_{c\Bbb R}(V)=\{p\}\cup Cl_{\Bbb R}(V\cap \Bbb R).$ Now for any open $W$  of $c\Bbb R$ with $p\in W,$ let $W'=W\cap V.$ Then $W'\cap \Bbb R$ is open in $\Bbb R$ and $Cl_{\Bbb R}(W'\cap \Bbb R)$ is not compact, but $\partial_{\Bbb R}(W'\cap \Bbb R)=\partial_{c\Bbb R}(W')$ IS compact. In $\Bbb R$ an open set with non-compact closure and compact boundary must cover a half-line.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma . Partial answer on MO https://mathoverflow.net/questions/365082/possible-cardinalities-of-the-remainders-of-compactifications-of-bbb-r/365158#365158

Comment: @AsafKaragila . Partial A on MO https://mathoverflow.net/questions/365082/possible-cardinalities-of-the-remainders-of-compactifications-of-bbb-r/365158#365158

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti . Partial A on MO. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/365082/possible-cardinalities-of-the-remainders-of-compactifications-of-bbb-r/365158#365158

Comment: @DanielWainfleet thanks for letting me know. I stumbled on [this paper](http://www.math.caltech.edu/SimonPapers/2.pdf) in which the main result is that if $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space and there is a continuous $g:[0,\infty)\to X$ with $g([a,\infty))$ dense for all $a$, then $[0,\infty)$ has a compactification with remainder $X$, which might be useful